# MongoDB: how to query based on date interval and one more condition that match all the date in interval

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo collection which stores information about products & it has an embedded array that stores its availability datewise.

```
{
  "product_id": "A",
  "name": "mountain bicycle",
  "cost_per_hour": "$5",
  "availability":[
    {
      "timestamp": ISODate("2018-11-19 18:30:00.000Z"),
      "available": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": ISODate("2018-12-20 18:30:00.000Z")
      "available": true
    },
    {
      "timestamp": ISODate("2018-12-21 18:30:00.000Z")
      "available": false
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to list all the products that are available on all dates in a given date interval.

> Example: If I query for date between ISODate("2018-11-19 18:30:00.000Z") To ISODate("2018-12-20 18:30:00.000Z") AND available: true, I should get a product with "product_id": "A", since its available on all dates between the date interval.
>
> But If I query between ISODate("2018-11-19 18:30:00.000Z") To ISODate("2018-12-21 18:30:00.000Z") AND available: true, I should NOT get any results since the product is NOT available on all dates in the date range.

I tried using $elemMatch but that returns products that are available in **at least 1** of the dates given in the interval, which I don't want.

Please guide.

Comment: I don't think its a duplicate. The post you have mentioned talks about projection, where as mine deals with querying embedded mongo array on multiple conditions & returning documents that match all the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find documents where *all* of an array field's elements pass a query, you can invert your query to look for the failure case (`available: false`), and then use [`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/#op._S_not) to only return the documents where that failure case doesn't occur:

```
db.test.find({
  availability: {$not: {$elemMatch: {
    timestamp: {$gte: ISODate("2018-11-19 18:30:00.000Z"), 
                $lte: ISODate("2018-12-21 18:30:00.000Z")},
    available: false
  }}}
})
```

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyHK. How can we do this for inversion for top-level documents i.e documents that are not a part of the array ?

Answer (score -1):

Folowing the documentation on:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/

at:

```
db.inventory.find( { "instock": { warehouse: "A", qty: 5 } } )
```

What you are looking for is something like:

```
db.StoreCollection.find( { 
         "availability": { 
              "timestamp": ISODate("2018-12-20 18:30:00.000Z")
              "available": true
          }
 })
```

Comment: Keep reading the documentation there and learn something. [Specify Multiple Conditions for Array of Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/). You're query here is completely wrong. You also appear to have misread the question.

Comment: Yes I read the docs before. The above query which you have suggested will only work if the document given in query exactly matches the document structure & order present in the collection you are querying. That is not the intended result am looking at. I am querying based on only 2 fields timestamp & available field.